6522 Clearing Interrupt flag of shift register without restarting it
The 6522 Via Adapter (R6522 in my case) has an internal shift register used for communication.
When shift a byte out in mode 5 (Shift out under T2 Control) an interrupt will occur after 8 pulsing and this interrupt can be cleared reading or writing to the SR Register, but the it also restart the shift register, so you end up in an infinite cycle of writing to clear out the interrupt flag.
Does anyone know if it is possible to clear the interrupt flag without restarting the shift register?

The datasheet, on page 13, describes the IFR as a "read/bit-clear register", hinting that a write operation to the IFR will permit you to clear an individual flag bit without affecting the others.
Failing that, try to first disable that particular interrupt using the IER register, and then clear the IFR interrupt flag with a regular read or write of SR. The procedure is also described on page 13 of the datasheet.
